# How can i get xml data from an URL using GDataXML parser in iPhone application development?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, gdata

I just want to know that how can I use url in GDataXML parser for extracting xml data. I have never used it before so please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked a non-descriptive question, so there's not much I can do to explain what you need help with.

```
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:someURL];
NSError *error;
GDataXMLDocument *doc = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data 
    options:0 error:&error]; 
NSLog(@"%@", doc.rootElement);
```

Take a look at the (numerous) tutorials on the 'net, such as [this one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml).